# Adding emoticon buttons during topic creation/edit

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, web

I'm trying to add emoticon buttons in my CreateTopic form.

Here's my HTML for the CreateTopic page:

```html
@using Reddit.Models
@model CreateTopicViewModel

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <section id="postForm">

            @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateTopic", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "control-label" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <button type="button" name="useEmoji"><i class="em em---1"></i></button>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Content, new { @class = "control-label" })
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Content, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = "8" })
                </div>
                <button type="submit" name="postTopic" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Post Topic</button>
            }
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

I read that it's not possible to make nested forms so the only idea I have left is creating a ButtonHandler action which gets called every time an emoticon button or Post Topic button is called to check if it's the Post Topic button being clicked or the emoticons, but that would not be very smooth IMO.
How should I go about this ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you need a server-side action for this? (By the way, a "button handler" is webforms terminology) Why can't you use client-side javascript?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. I have no idea, I'm a beginner. I'm still a novice in JS so that's why I thought I could do it serverside.